# not able to access some routes in laravel

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I am getting a 404 when trying to access any other routes except '/' in my laravel project

my dhavalchheda.conf file is as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@dhavalchheda.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dhavalchheda/public/
ServerName dhavalchheda.com
ServerAlias www.dhavalchheda.com
<Directory /var/www/html/dhavalchheda/>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/dhavalchheda.com-error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/dhavalchheda.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

my laravel folder structure is

dhavalchheda -> full laravel project

I am not able to understand the mistake so please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to enable your rewrite module of apache service. So try with below command to run your all other routes:

> sudo a2enmod rewrite

and restart the apache service:

> sudo service apache2 restart

Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/)

Follow these steps will help you.